# Why does my audio playback freeze ActionListners?

Tags: java, audio, java-8

Im using the this [javaPlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) to playback my sounds.

But in my larger
project it freezes/ignores almost every input `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and `ActionListner`s that alter the frame content. I tried to repruduce the issue in this snippet.

The `btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Check1"));` is not applied to my button. Only if I comment out the whole `try/catch-block` the `"Check1"` is also reached.
What could be the problem? I already tried to send the playerpart with Swing.invokeLater to another thread.

```
package mainMVC;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class Alone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
        btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Check"));
        
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.pack();
        
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/EgyptianTavernFullofGuitarists_1.mp3"))
        {
            Player player = new Player(fis);
            player.play();
        } catch (IOException | JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Check1"));
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's a problem. I've tested your code in my IDE, and it works. During start Frame, music plays. `ActionListener` returns `Check` and music doesn't stop, same `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: there is a second one btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Check1"));

Comment: the point is that a button `btn` should returns value `Check` instead of `Check1` ?

Comment: just comment out the whole try/catch-block and it will print both
because its two different actionlisteners I add

Comment: okay, that's right, and why you need two `ActionListener` on one button. I think this's normal occurrence. Tell me exactly what's wrong here, cuz I don't understand.

Comment: please read my question and answer carefully
the second ActionListener is just for testing purpose

Comment: Sorry, but I tried my best, and still can't resolve this trouble, I hope you do it. Good luck:)

Comment: broo I already answerd my own question :) just read my answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I found that execution is stopped till the playback of the file is finished.**

I managed it with a manual thread creation. Now both "Check" and "Check1" are printed.

`File: Audio.java`

```
package mainMVC;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

class Audio extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/EgyptianTavernFullofGuitarists_1.mp3"))
        {
            Player player = new Player(fis);
            player.play();
        } catch (IOException | JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`File: Alone.java`

```
package mainMVC;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Alone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
        btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Check"));
        
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.pack();

        Audio myThread = new Audio();
        myThread.start();
        
        btn.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Check1"));
        
    }
}
```